# Comparing Dates - Date.ValueOf() seems to not output correctly - returns 01:00:00

Tags: date, datetime

Maybe I'm misunderstanding Date.ValueOf() - but I'm not expecting this behavior... I'm was thinking the dates would be the same.

```
List<Limits__c> mostRecentBatch= [select id, lastModifiedDate from Limits__c order by lastModifiedDate DESC limit 1];
if(Date.ValueOf(mostRecentBatch[0].LastModifiedDate) > System.Today()){
    //next batch after midnight GMT (insert new batch)
    System.debug(Date.ValueOf(mostRecentBatch[0].LastModifiedDate));
    System.Debug(System.Today());
}
else{
    //this doesn't hit
}

1st debug: //09:00:55:017 USER_DEBUG [15]|DEBUG|2018-06-14 01:00:00 -> where does the 01:00:00 come from? (The real LastModifiedDate is 2018-06-14T13:46:41.000Z)
2nd debug: //09:00:55:017 USER_DEBUG [16]|DEBUG|2018-06-14 00:00:00
```

Shouldn't these be the same? Isn't Date.valueOf(Datetime) supposed to return midnight GMT, not 1:00 AM? Should I try to check for this a different way?

Comment: Its summer time going on, BST which is 1 hour ahead of GMT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date.valueOf accounts for DST, and ends up creating a new Date value, which is probably not your intent. Instead, you'll probably want to use the DateTime.date() method:

```
if(mostRecentBatch[0].LastModifiedDate.date() > System.Today()) {
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks Fox... Daylight savings time - who would have guessed. That's a much better way to compare.